# How to create tensor with shape(?,) and dtype=string from image with tensorflow in python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a trained model with input layer specified below:

```
Model input:  [<tf.Tensor 'encoded_image_string_tensor:0' shape=(None,) dtype=string>, <tf.Tensor 'key:0' shape=(None,) dtype=string>]
```

I have problem to create a tensor with these properties. Either i get right dtype but then i get *shape()*. Or i get a nonempty shape but *dtype=uint8* or similar. Any tip on how to read, create and input my image to right format. 
The images that I want to input are *grayscale*, *jpg*, *3232x583* pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it with help of this anwser ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58757328/12971979))
I read it as a image with OpenCV. Encode it to jpg. Transform it to byte array. And make it to tensorflow with tf.constant(). Feels like the convertion from file to byte array could be made in a better way but i leave it with this for now.

code:

```
img = cv2.imread('IMAGEPATH')
flag, bts = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img) 
byte_arr = [bts[:,0].tobytes()]
tensor_string = tf.constant(byte_arr)
```

gives this which works:

> Tensor("Const_14:0", shape=(1,), dtype=string)

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None, ], name="encoder_image_string_tensor")
print(a)
```

which prints

`Tensor("encoder_image_string_tensor:0", shape=(?,), dtype=string)`

For feeding value into this Tensor you can use `sess.run` and the `feed_dict` parameter inside this function.

To get the image in the right dimension you can do:

```py
import cv2
im = cv2.imread("abc.jpg")
my_img = np.squeeze(np.reshape(im, [-1, 1]))
sess.run([], feed_dict={a: my_img})
```

I am sourcing my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33862534/6997665).

Comment: Hm i dont really understad what to do with the feed_dict. 
Tensorflow API tells sess.run(y, feed_dict={a: x}) but what will be my 'y' and 'x' value?  I either get the error that x cant be a tensor or that x has shape () but needs to have shape(none,)

And the par to get image in the right dimensions gives it wrong dtype instead :/

Comment: @e_akesson I'm sorry for being  little vague. I have updated the answer. The first parameter to `sess.run()` is some variable in your graph, that requires `a`, to be computed. For now I have kept it blank

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work either. I still get the wrong shape error. I solved it in another way (post it below). But thanks alot for your time and effort helping me.

Comment: @e_akesson that's great. Two things, one, if your answer worked for you, mark it as accepted and second, if this answer (or any answer for that matter) helped you, consider upvoting. It is essential to encourage people to write more answers.